# Create an object via reflection from a satellite assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection

I have two assemblies / projects with DLL as output: Models and Logic

Inside the Logic DLL I want to create an object of a specific model via reflection (The project is referenced and I am able to manually create an instance)

```
MyNameSpace.Models.Foo foo = new MyNameSpace.Models.Foo(); // works
Type type = Type.GetType("MyNameSpace.Models.Foo"); // returns null
```

How can I create an object of `MyNameSpace.Models.Foo`? Apparently the type does not resolve. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at using [`Activator.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx). For example:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("Foo.dll");

Type type = assembly.GetType("TheNamspace.TheType");

object instanceOfMyType = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Answer (score 2):

You would have to use the AssemblyQualifiedName. See this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname.aspx for more info.

In your case, something like:

```
MyNamespace.Models.Foo, MyAssembly, Version=1.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b17a5c561934e089
```

The PublicKeyToken could be longer if you've signed your assemblies.

If you're not sure, just create an instance of the object the usual way, and then do:

```
Type objType = typeof(System.Array);

// Print the full assembly name.
Console.WriteLine ("Full assembly name: {0}.", objType.Assembly.FullName.ToString()); 

// Print the qualified assembly name.
Console.WriteLine ("Qualified assembly name: {0}.", objType.AssemblyQualifiedName.ToString());
```

(shamelessly nicked from the aforementioned article)

Answer (score 0):

Type.GetType argument is AssemblyQualifiedName: from [MSDN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185907/create-an-object-via-reflection-from-a-satellite-assembly)